# Use arguments to pass parameter information to cURL script

Tags: bash, shell-script, curl, arguments

I am trying to write a script where the user can pass startDate and endDate via arguments when running the script. Here's my script (saved as test.sh)-

```
VAR="$(curl -f -X POST -H 'X-API-TOKEN: XXXXXX' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"format": "csv", "startDate": $1, "endDate": $2}' 'https://xxx.qualtrics.com/export-responses' | sed -E -n 's/.*([^"]+).+/\1/p')"
echo $VAR
```

When running the script I type the following -

```
~/test.sh '"2020-05-13T17:11:00Z","2020-05-13T20:32:00Z"'
```

The script throws an error.

Comment: I did come across the article you linked above, however the use case below helped me comprehend better - Thanks @AndyDalton

Comment: Would you mind editing your question to indicate _what_ error is thrown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using $1 and $2 inside single quotes, and the shell doesn't expand variables inside single quotes.

Consider, a simplified example:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

VAR="$(echo '{"format": "csv", "startDate": $1, "endDate": $2}')"
echo $VAR
```

If I run that, notice that I get a literal `$1` and `$2`:

```
$ ./example hi ho
{"format": "csv", "startDate": $1, "endDate": $2}
```

You need do get those variables outside of single quotes.  One option is the following (I've also added the necessary quote literals around the variables:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

VAR="$(echo "{\"format\": \"csv\", \"startDate\": \"$1\", \"endDate\": \"$2\"}")"
echo $VAR
```

Now I get:

```
$ ./example hi ho
{"format": "csv", "startDate": "hi", "endDate": "ho"}
```

Comment: You should pretty much always put variable references inside double-quotes, e.g. `echo "$VAR"` instead of just `echo $VAR`. Also, unless you're doing something else with `VAR`, skip the `VAR=$(cmd); echo "$VAR"`, and just run `cmd` directly.

Comment: @GordonDavisson please see the code in the OP.  I don't disagree with your suggestions, but I see no need to introduce extraneous changes that could distract from the solution to the problem the OP is facing.